# In AppleScript, how can I set a timeout on NSURLConnection's sendSynchronousRequest?

Tags: applescript

I wrote an AppleScript function that takes a URL for an API endpoint, and returns `true` or `false` depending on whether there is any response to an HTTP "get":

```
use AppleScript version "2.4"
use framework "Foundation"

on ping(api_url)
    -- Create the request object.
    set ca to current application
    set url_string to ca's |NSURL|'s URLWithString:api_url
    set request to ca's |NSURLRequest|'s requestWithURL:url_string
    
    -- Try to connect to the endpoint.
    set responseData to missing value
    set status to missing value
    
    set _response to ca's NSHTTPURLResponse's alloc()'s init()
    set {_data, _error} to ca's NSURLConnection's sendSynchronousRequest:request ¬
        returningResponse:_response |error|:(reference)
    
    if _error is missing value then
        -- No error => connected.
        return true
    else if class of _error is ca's NSURLError then
        return false
    else
        -- I'm unsure this can ever happen, but let's play it safe.
        return false
    end if
end ping

-- Simple test.

if ping("https://google.com") then
    log "yes"
else
    log "no"
end if
```

Now I'd like to add a timeout parameter, such that if there is no response within the given time period, the function returns `false`. I have not been able to figure out how to do this. Some Googling let me to find examples of using `timeoutInterval` with the NSURLConnection or NSURLRequest object; unfortunately, when I try to add that, I get errors about "unknown selector". My question probably has an easy answer, but I just don't have enough experience with AppleScript (it was hard enough to get this much working!).

**How can I add a timeout parameter to this function?**

*Update 2024-01-26*: the way that I tried to add the timeout is to change lines 15-16 to be this:

```
set {_data, _error} to ca's NSURLConnection's sendSynchronousRequest:request ¬
    timeoutInterval:5 returningResponse:_response |error|:(reference)
```

I also tried:

```
set {_data, _error} to ca's NSURLConnection's sendSynchronousRequest:request ¬
    returningResponse:_response |error|:(reference) ¬ 
    cachePolicy:(ca's NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData) ¬
    timeoutInterval:5
```

The error message (when running in [Script Debugger](https://latenightsw.com)) is always like this:

```
+[NSURLConnection
sendSynchronousRequest:timeoutInterval:returningResponse:error:]:
unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1eee55848
```

Comment: Using `requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:` seems to work for me, but I don't have an URL that delays long enough to timeout.  What specific error were you getting?

Comment: Hmmm … okay. Maybe I was trying to use the wrong syntax. I'll update the question to show an example of what I tried.

Comment: `cachePolicy` and `timeoutInterval ` are properties of `NSURLRequest` not `NSURLConnection`. As the properties are read-only you have to create **request** with `requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:`.

Comment: Well, no wonder it didn't work :-). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to people's comments, I was able to realize the mistake and make things work. Here is a new version that adds a timeout parameter and is improved in some other ways. The key ingredient is the addition of **both** `cachePolicy` and `timeoutInterval` to the `NSURLRequest` call – attempting to add *only* `timeoutInterval` results in an error:

```
use AppleScript version "2.5"
use framework "Foundation"

on ping(api_url, max_time)
    -- Create the request object.
    set ca to current application
    set url_string to ca's |NSURL|'s URLWithString:api_url
    set ignore_cache to ca's NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
    set request to ca's NSURLRequest's alloc()'s initWithURL:url_string ¬
        cachePolicy:(ignore_cache) timeoutInterval:max_time
    
    -- Try to connect.
    set {conn, resp, err} to ca's NSURLConnection's ¬
        sendSynchronousRequest:request ¬
            returningResponse:(reference) |error|:(reference)
    
    -- No error object => connected.
    return (err is missing value)
end ping
```

Here is a simple test script:

```
if ping("https://httpstat.us/504?sleep=3000", 5) then
    log "yes (expected)"
else
    log "no (unexpected)"
end if

if ping("https://httpstat.us/504?sleep=3000", 2) then
    log "yes (unexpected)"
else
    log "no (expected)"
end if
```